Why does my wifi networks dissappear when my screen sleep/suspends on 24.04.1?
I just dual booted to 24.04.1 on my laptop. Whenever I open ubuntu I connect to wifi like usual. But when my screen sleeps or it enters suspend, whether I close it or it auto-sleeps, all networks just dissappear.
I've tried:

sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager

Changed wifi.powersave to = 2

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Ran:
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system-sleep/restart-network-manager.sh
Created script: #!/bin/sh case $1 in post) systemctl restart NetworkManager ;; esac
and then sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/restart-network-manager.sh

Updated drivers sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

Checked rfkill list; not blocked btw


All networks still disappear after suspend. It's like it's looking for networks but just never finds it
Ideas anyone?

For details of the 6 power states (not all are implemented) are found in the answer to this question: -  https://superuser.com/questions/71835/what-is-the-difference-between-these-four-sleep-states Note: Other than S0 (fully powered), the rest all have the CPU at least stopped - and most not powered. So it can't run anything. I suspect what you need is to just turn the screen off.  The following link might give you some ideas https://systembash.com/how-to-turn-off-your-monitor-via-command-line-in-ubuntu/

This was a great help to figuring out the answer dude thx

So the answer was like @david said to make the screen sleep. I'll go through it step by step for the complete beginners as well:
Enter terminal(Ctrl + alt + T by default):
Enter sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
sudo triggers you to write your password so write it and press 'Enter' to open the file
Find the line: #HandleLidSwitch=suspend
Remove the #
Change the line to HandleLidSwitch=lock
I changed HandleLidSwitchExternalPower and HandleLidSwitchDocked as well so it works when its connected to an external screen or charging too
Then you press "Ctrl + X", press "Y", and then finally press "Enter"
NOTE: The next step will restart the pc. Save anything you need to be safe. When you run the command the screen will turn black, then show lock screen and after you've logged in it will show black again. To return to normal press Ctrl + C.
Restart by writing : sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind
And now it should work!
NB: Keep in mind that this means that everytime the screen is closed in ubuntu it isn't completely suspended. So to suspend you have to press suspend in the top right menu or manually suspend in another way. Just so your laptop doesn't overheat in its sleeve like mine did
